# Using a metaclass depending on configuration

Tags: python

I have a class that I want to set a metaclass for depending on what is configured, example:

```
use_metaclass = True

class B(object):  pass

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = B
```

However, if the configuration (use_metaclass) is False, I would not like the metaclass to be set for A.

How can I implement this? I realize that a class is an instance of a metaclass, so I guess this has to be set in A's definition in some way rather than after A has been instantiated.

Example what I want to "accomplish" but won't work due to what's said above:

```
use_metaclass = True

class B(object):  pass

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        if use_metaclass:
            self.__metaclass__ = B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put conditional logic in the class body if you need to:

```
class A(object):
    if use_metaclass:
        __metaclass__ = B
```

This gets evaluated at class definition time, so you need to make sure `use_metaclass` is set to the desired value before the class is loaded (you can't change the metaclass later).

In Python 3, where metaclasses are declared differently, you'd need to use the `if`/`else` ternary operator in the `class` line:

```
class A(metaclass=B if use_metaclass else type):
    pass
```

If `use_metaclass` is `False`, it will specify `type` as the metaclass. That's fine, since `type` is the default metaclass if nothing is declared (and all metaclasses in Python 3 must derive from `type`).